# How to initialize strings that are taken from an input file to convert into long integers and alter using functions

Tags: c, math, initialization

I am trying to write a program in C that reads from an input file which contains a list of strings with timestamps in the format dd/mm/yyyy-hh:mm:ss and converts these strings into long integers. These long integers are then converted in seconds and the difference from the year 2000 is calculated.

The two functions I have written work as intended when dealing with a single timestamp inputted manually in a separate program but fails to initialize when reading from the text file. I am also unsure how to make the program iterate throughout the entire text file to convert each string sequentially.

1. input from 1st string in text file = 29/11/2021-15:33:56
2. expected 1st output in the output file = 694199036
3. actual output = initialization of 'char' from 'char *' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX_FILENAME_LEN 256
#define MAX_STRINGS 100
#define MAX_LENGTH 50

long long timestamp_to_long (const char *timestamp) //converts timestamp to integer
{
  // Initialize a long integer variable to store the result
  long long result = 0;

  // Use a pointer to iterate through the timestamp string
  const char *ptr = timestamp;

  // Iterate through the timestamp string until the null character is reached
  while (*ptr)
    {
      // If the current character is a digit, add it to the result
      if (*ptr >= '0' && *ptr <= '9')
    {
      result = result * 10 + (*ptr - '0');
    }
      // Move to the next character
      ptr++;
    }

  return result;
}

long long timeStampToSeconds (long long result) //outputs seconds difference from start date
{
  long long startsec = 63115200000; //2000*31557600
  long long daysToSec = ((result / 1000000000000) % 100) * (24 * 3600);
  long long monthsToSec =((result / 10000000000) % 100) * (24 * 3600 * (365.25 / 12));
  long long yearsToSec = ((result / 1000000) % 10000) * 31557600;
  long long hoursToSec = ((result / 10000) % 100) * 3600;
  long long minutesToSec = ((result / 100) % 100) * 60;
  long long secondsToSec = result % 100;
  long long totalSec =
    daysToSec + monthsToSec + yearsToSec + hoursToSec + minutesToSec +
    secondsToSec;
  long long difference = totalSec - startsec;

  return difference;
}

int main ()
{
  char strings[MAX_STRINGS][MAX_LENGTH];
  char input_filename[MAX_FILENAME_LEN];
  char output_filename[MAX_FILENAME_LEN];
  char *p;
  int num_strings = 0;


  printf ("Enter the name of the input file: ");
  scanf ("%s", input_filename);

  printf ("Enter the name of the output file: ");
  scanf ("%s", output_filename);

  // Open the input file
  FILE *fileptr = fopen (input_filename, "r");
  if (fileptr == NULL)
    {
      printf ("Error opening file!\n");
      return 1;
    }

  // Read in the strings from the file
  while (fgets (strings[num_strings], MAX_LENGTH, fileptr) != NULL)
    {
      // Remove newline character from the string
      int length = strlen (strings[num_strings]);
      if (strings[num_strings][length - 1] == '\n')
    {
      strings[num_strings][length - 1] = '\0';
    }
      num_strings++;
    }
  p = (char *) malloc (num_strings + 1);

  if (p == NULL)
    {
      printf ("Unable to allocate memory");
      exit (1);
    }

  // Close the input file
  fclose (fileptr);


  char timestamp = ("%s", *strings);

  // Convert the timestamp to a long integer
  long long result = timestamp_to_long (timestamp);
  long long difference = timeStampToSeconds (result);


  // Open the output file
  fileptr = fopen (output_filename, "w");
  if (fileptr == NULL)
    {
      printf ("Error opening file!\n");
      return 1;
    }

  // Write the sorted strings to the file
  for (int i = 0; i < num_strings; i++)
    {
      fprintf (fileptr, "%lld\n", difference);
    }

  // Close the file
  fclose (fileptr);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I did some extra digging and found a solution that I am going to leave here, in case somebody in the future has a similar issue.

The main issue I had was `char timestamp = ("%s", *strings);`; this is wrong and can be fixed by changing it to `char *timestamps = strings[i]` and adding a simple loop `(int i = 0; i < num_strings; i++)` to iterate through the entire input list.

I also included the `fprintf` function in the loop to write the difference each time the `for` loop iterated, which I should have done in the first place.